# How to create GitHub issue template that is only visible to certain team?

Tags: github, templates, open-source, voting

Is it possible to limit the visibility of a GitHub issue template to a certain team?

An example use case is using GitHub issues to hold a vote amongst a maintainer team. It would be useful to somehow specify the markdown or yaml template file such that only the maintainer team members can utilize this template, as they should be the only ones calling for a vote, and utilizing a template will keep things tidy and consistent.